# Change the default types of phone numbers for new contacts in MS Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm trying to change the default "types" of phone numbers shown when I add new contacts in MS Outlook 2007. As a default, it shows
 - Business
 - Home
 - Business Fax
 - Mobile

I'd like to change that default order. Any help would be greatly appreciated!